# Hazelcast warns "Received a JoinRequest with a different packet version repeatedly"

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-cache

Upgraded from Hazlecast 3.0.x to 3.5.2 and when two nodes connects using multicast i see this in log repeatedly..

Node1:

```
WARNING: [x.x.x.x]:5701 [hazelCluster] [3.5.2] Received a JoinRequest with a different packet version! This -> 4, Incoming -> 1, Sender -> /x.x.x.x
Oct 12, 2015 11:57:15 AM com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.MulticastService
```

Node2:

```
WARNING: [x.x.x.x]:5701 [hazelCluster] [3.5.2] Received a JoinRequest with a different packet version! This -> 4, Incoming -> 1, Sender -> /x.x.x.x
Oct 12, 2015 11:53:52 AM com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.MulticastService
```

Hazelcast network configuration :

```
<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="true">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.4</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>34466</multicast-port>
            <multicast-time-to-live>64</multicast-time-to-live>
            <multicast-timeout-seconds>2</multicast-timeout-seconds>
        </multicast>
    </join>
</network>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like there was an older version of Hazelcast still running on the same network, after updating the multicast IP/PORT the problem was solved.

here's a link : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/multicast.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution :)